# What can be Drag type for SWT tree Node

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an SWT Tree ,  which has image and other text and multilevel children.
Now I want to drag this tree node , but I am not able to get the proper transfer type for this.
So once I drag I dont get the dragging image .
Is there any default Transfer type available for the same.

Following is my Tree-
[image]

I used following Transfers but didnt work-

```
Transfer[] types = new Transfer[] {FileTransfer.getInstance(),ImageTransfer.getInstance() };
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DragandDropexamplesnippetdragleafitemsinatree.htm)?

Comment: yes , its using textTransfer , but for my case , its not only Text , so I want something which actually accept anything to drag

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure what you are asking for, but this code works even with `Image`s.

If your text cannot be used as an identifier, you can come up with something else:

```
private static Map<String, Image>   mapping = new HashMap<String, Image>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Image[] images = new Image[] { display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WARNING),
            display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_ERROR), display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_INFORMATION),
            display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_QUESTION) };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Item " + i);
        item.setImage(images[i % images.length]);
        mapping.put("Item " + i, images[i % images.length]);
    }

    initDnD(display, tree);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void initDnD(final Display display, final Tree tree)
{
    Transfer[] types = new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance() };
    int operations = DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_LINK;

    final DragSource source = new DragSource(tree, operations);
    source.setTransfer(types);

    final TreeItem[] dragSourceItem = new TreeItem[1];
    source.addDragListener(new DragSourceListener()
    {
        public void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event)
        {
            TreeItem[] selection = tree.getSelection();
            if (selection.length > 0 && selection[0].getItemCount() == 0)
            {
                event.doit = true;
                dragSourceItem[0] = selection[0];
            }
            else
            {
                event.doit = false;
            }
        };

        public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event)
        {
            event.data = dragSourceItem[0].getText();
        }

        public void dragFinished(DragSourceEvent event)
        {
            if (event.detail == DND.DROP_MOVE)
                dragSourceItem[0].dispose();
            dragSourceItem[0] = null;
        }
    });

    DropTarget target = new DropTarget(tree, operations);
    target.setTransfer(types);
    target.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter()
    {
        public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event)
        {
            event.feedback = DND.FEEDBACK_SCROLL;
            if (event.item != null)
            {
                TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.item;
                Point pt = display.map(null, tree, event.x, event.y);
                Rectangle bounds = item.getBounds();
                if (pt.y < bounds.y + bounds.height / 3)
                {
                    event.feedback |= DND.FEEDBACK_INSERT_BEFORE;
                }
                else if (pt.y > bounds.y + 2 * bounds.height / 3)
                {
                    event.feedback |= DND.FEEDBACK_INSERT_AFTER;
                }
            }
        }

        public void drop(DropTargetEvent event)
        {
            if (event.data == null)
            {
                event.detail = DND.DROP_NONE;
                return;
            }
            String text = (String) event.data;
            if (event.item != null)
            {
                TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.item;
                Point pt = display.map(null, tree, event.x, event.y);
                Rectangle bounds = item.getBounds();

                TreeItem[] items = tree.getItems();
                int index = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                {
                    if (items[i] == item)
                    {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (pt.y < bounds.y + bounds.height / 3)
                {
                    TreeItem newItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE, index);
                    newItem.setText(text);
                    newItem.setImage(mapping.get(text));
                }
                else if (pt.y > bounds.y + 2 * bounds.height / 3)
                {
                    TreeItem newItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE, index + 1);
                    newItem.setText(text);
                    newItem.setImage(mapping.get(text));
                }
                else
                {
                    TreeItem newItem = new TreeItem(item, SWT.NONE);
                    newItem.setText(text);
                    newItem.setImage(mapping.get(text));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This coming up with something else is my concern. I actually wanted to accept anything to drag irrespective of text or any kind of Object available over my RCP application. So How to do that ...Ideally i believe inheriting Transfer and do something may work , and thats where I am working on.